# google map extract LatLng of pinned location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Trying to extract Lat and Lng of a location using google map autocomplete method to get the location/place and output it in a hidden input.

I read somewhere that place.geometry.location is equal to LatLng but when I do a console.log these lines I get location.lat(); not a function. Also can someone point me how to output the LatLng in the input and update when dragged the marker.

```
var locPosition = place.geometry.location;
            var LocLat = location.lat();
            var LocLng = location.lng();
            console.log(LocLat);
```

Okay: found the way to console lat and lng separately by doing so.

```
var locPositionLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var locPositionLng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

found my way to output in the field by doing so, but unless its wrong then please correct it.

```
$('#lat').val(locPositionLat);
$('#lng').val(locPositionLng);
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfofu92g/

Edit: follow up question, how do I get the getPosition of the pin when dragged this  time.

Comment: huh? it was marked down without explanation? thought that's against the rules?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

You can output them to the field by:

```
document.getElementByName("lat").value = "somevalue"; 
//same for Lng.
```

As for the updated marker position after drag you need to have a "dragend" listener, something like:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function(event) {

             document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();

});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I've tried this but it wasn't really doing anything though. Can you update the fiddle to show pls.

Comment: I want to update the lat and lng as you drag the marker which that event listener should be doing but can't get the getPosition working.

Comment: I understand, I'll mess around with it. Should be working, I'm probably missing something simple though.

Comment: Thanks, would really appreciate it big time.

Comment: I think its just the google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function() { that isn't working inside the whole function :/ but I could be wrong

Comment: where about in the func did you put it? :/ im still not seeing it and no error log.

Comment: fixed now, how can I get the postcode of the searched location?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "postcode of the searched location"